# form input not working?

Tags: html, css, input

I have a website [www.edigitalnepal.com/exam/](http://www.edigitalnepal.com/exam/). When i login there, i cannot click on the input field since it becomes unclickable. But i don't know what is the issue there. Can you please help me with this issue.
To login, type **student** in both field.
My html code for the input box is-

```
<div class="search">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." onkeyup="Search(this.value)">
                     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>


                     <div class="search-result">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled nomargin" id="search_result_show">

                            </ul>
                     </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: what does Search() do?

Comment: it searches all the data from the database

Comment: Well it's obvious that your search starts executing and blocks everything. If all you can answer is *it searches all the data from the database* then nobody has enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body has a class `.modal-open` but in your style.css file you set it up this way :

```
.modal-open .login-popup {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

According to the documentation in [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) the "none" value works like this :

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

So I guess you will have either to remove this value, to change it, or to set another one for your input.